# Why CLLocationManager's event happens even I don't move my iPad

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I set up CLLocationManager in .h file as an instance variable.

```
CLLocationManager   *locationManager;
```

And initialize it as below.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0;
```

I thought that if I don't move my iOS device and just dragging the map won't make an event. But when dragging the map, sometimes

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

is called. The timing is not same, I mean sometimes it happens suddenly, sometime it happens after a while, about 30secs.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple - GPS is not exact. Any GPS device calculates your position over and over. But due to it's inexact calculations, the results can give different position results even if you are not moving. The difference can be a few inches (centimeters) or many feet (meters).

So as you sit there with your unmoving iOS device, the location manager gets updated GPS results. If a result says you moved a few feet (meter) then your app gets an update.

The opposite is true. It's possible that you could move but not get a position update. This is far less likely because the inexact position update is unlikely to be in the exact same direction you just happened to move.

One thing you could do is keep an eye on the iOS device's accelerometer data. If you get a position update but the accelerometer indicates you haven't moved, you can ignore the update.

Answer (score 0):

It might be horizontalAccuracy or verticalAccuracy changing, making location more precise... Also this method is deprecated with iOS6, maybe you should use locationManager:didUpdateLocations

Comment: Thank you for telling me that this method is deprecated. I'll try to use didUpdateLocations instead.

I put my iPad on the desk and don' touch it....

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you think that moving the position of a map view has something to do with the CLLocationManager callback function that returns the user's location... It doesn't. Dragging the map has nothing to do with getting a location update from the OS.

You can't control when you get these updates, they just happen when the operating system is able to determine a reasonably accurate location using GPS/Wifi.